# compression-webpack-plugin vs AWS CloudFront compression

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-cloudfront

AWS CloudFront has the option to compress files ([see here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-gzip-compression-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/))

What are the pros and cons of using AWS CloudFront gzip compression vs using the compression-webpack-plugin?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront compresses content on the fly and it has certain limitation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

### The common problem is

### CloudFront is busy
In rare cases, when a CloudFront edge location is unusually busy, some files might not be compressed.

This is most common problem because if this happens CF caches a non compressed copy and serve it until you clear the cache.

compression-webpack-plugin on the other hand compresses at the disk which is more helpful.